# In bot rewards (discord.py) by voting on top.gg / discordbotlist

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, webhooks

When a user votes for my bot on either of the sites, it sends them a DM and I want it to do other things too but for the sake of simplicity can we use a `print` statement to be triggered once the user votes? is this going to be done using webhooks? I'm totally new to those.

Please give me an example code of how it could be done!

Answer (score 2):

top.gg uses their own API, a full reference can be found here: https://top.gg/api/docs#pylib

You would first need to install their module which can be done with `pip install dblpy`

In their documentation, it shows many examples of usage and how you can implement them in your code. Simply all it does is, runs a task loop, waiting for a user to upvote, and within your code you can simply do what ever you want with the reward. As well as many other usages they provide, but hope this helps.

Comment: thank you! but i still don't understand how to trigger an event when a user votes :(

Comment: The events are triggered by the library itself, there's no need to do it manually. You can check out the examples in the link **Cohen** provided @SkillzGamin